# Javascript: Como pegar um array de objetos dentro de um filho de um array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, front-end, estrutura-de-dados, ecmascript-6

Tenho o seguinte objeto de exemplo:

```
const empresa = {
    nome: 'Tal tal',
    endereco: 'taltaltal',
    groupos: [
        {
        nome: 'taltaltal',
        codenome: 'tal',

        as: [
            {
                nome: 'grupo a',
                apelido: 'ga'
            },
            {
                nome: 'grupo a',
                apelido: 'ga'
            },
            {
                nome: 'grupo a',
                apelido: 'ga'
            },
            {
                nome: 'grupo a',
                apelido: 'ga'
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        nome: 'taltaltal',
        codenome: 'tal',

        as: [
            {
                nome: 'grupo a',
                apelido: 'ga'
            },
            {
                nome: 'grupo a',
                apelido: 'ga'
            },
            {
                nome: 'grupo a',
                apelido: 'ga'
            },
            {
                nome: 'grupo a',
                apelido: 'ga'
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        nome: 'taltaltal',
        codenome: 'tal',

        as: [
            {
                nome: 'grupo a',
                apelido: 'ga'
            },
            {
                nome: 'grupo b',
                apelido: 'gb'
            },
            {
                nome: 'grupo c',
                apelido: 'gc'
            },
            {
                nome: 'grupo d',
                apelido: 'gd'
            },
        ]
    },
],

}
```

Gostaria de pegar o array de objetos grupos->as :

```
grupos: [
   ...
   as: {
      ...
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a estrutura da const empresa.

Se você deseja obter todos `as` da lista `groupos`:

```
for (let grupo of empresa.groupos) { 
    console.log(grupo.as);
}
```

Se você deseja filtrar por codenome de grupo:

```
for (let grupo of empresa.groupos) { 
   if (grupo.codenome === "tal") {
      console.log(grupo.as);
      break;
   }
}
```

Você também pode obter o item da lista utilizando o indice da posição:

```
console.log(empresa.groupos[0].as);
```

Também existe o bom e velho for loop básico:

```
for (let indice = 0; indice < empresa.groupos.length; indice++) {
    const grupo = empresa.groupos[indice];
    console.log(grupo.as);
}
```

Existem também outras maneiras de varrer um array além do `for...of` [neste link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Consulte_tamb%C3%A9m)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar um array apenas com os elementos `as`:

```
var grupos = [];

$.each(empresa.groupos, function(index, element) {
    grupos.push(element.as);
});
```